# Bash Startup not showing color on bash input line

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm very new to bash and have started learning it only recently. I'm working on a Windows Machine, using Ubuntu 18.04.1. I have found, after a recent computer crash, that when I call bash on my machine, the first line in bash is not colorized (as it would be normally). My process is as follows: Open cmd prompt. Type in bash. Only when I call bash -I, bash -i, bash --debugger, etc,...  or bash a second time will it be colored. I have checked ~/.bashrc file to see if there appeared to be anything out of order, and to my best knowledge things seemed OK. Does anyone have any familiarity with this issue?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bash app appears to be corrupt. Uninstall it and reinstall it. You won't lose anything that you have made.